# How to store in `address` two kinds of addresses at once?

Tags: addresses, hash, cryptography, keccak

I have a set of `address` values, each of them can contain a real Ethereum account (user account or contract) or a "virtual" address (an address pseudo-randomly generated by my contract, in fact first 160 bits of an NFT token ID).

I want virtual addresses to be distinguished from real accounts by being less than a certain `2**N`.

I generate a virtual address like this:

```
address next = address(truncate(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(previous))));
```

where `truncate()` takes the lower N bits.

How to choose N for both:

- low probability that a real address will be less than `2**N` and mistook for a virtual address;
- low probability that two virtual addresses will clash.

Comment: An address bits should be random since they are derived from a strong hash function keccak. So having an address withe the first N bits set to zero has probality 1/(2**N). I've seen vanity addresses with non random 11 hex digits (N=44), perhaps N=80 is good enough.